# Analysis 1B: Proof that if $f\colon [0,1] \to \mathbf R$ is not continuous, then it is not regulated

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Question is basically just what is in the title. I am trying to prove that the function $f\colon [0,1] \to \mathbf R$ being not continuous implies that the function is not regulated over the interval $[0,1]$. This is an undergrad analysis course question.

For those unfamiliar with the notion of 'regulated', it means that a left and right limit exists at each $x \in [0,1]$ in this case.

The original q is asking to show that the above function is continuous IFF it is regulated. I have shown cont => regulated but I’m struggling to show reg => cont, so I’m trying the contrapositive (hence the question).

Thank you!

Comment: The left and right limits can exist but not agree. So it would seem a function can be regulated but not continuous. Would be good to clarify the definition of regulated.

Comment: @Jeff Regulated => Continuous (at least I thought) so I’m using the contrapositive to prove that not continuous implies not regulated. It’s supposed to be the second half of an IFF proof. The full question gives that function and asks to show that f is continuous if and only if it is regulated.

Comment: Just wondering for function defined by $f(x) = 0$ if $x < 0.5$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $x \geq 0.5$, I assume it's regulated?

Comment: @user559675 Yes that would be regulated since you can find left and right limits of the function at every point

Comment: but it's not continuous, so is it really a iff question?

Comment: @user559675 It is definitely an Iff question I’ve been asked yep. f:[0,1] into R. Show it’s continuous IFF it’s regulated

Comment: Yes, but what I gave you is a counter example?

Comment: @user559675 I mean, it is possible that I’m understanding and that it may not be a regulated function that you’ve given. I could just be massively confused.

Comment: Can you give a screen shot? According to wikipedia, "The set of discontinuities of a regulated function of bounded variation BV is countable for such functions have only jump-type of discontinuities." So either the question is wrong or your professor use a different definition.